# Fluent migrator extend withColumns

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

I wan to add an extension method for Fluent migrator to have something like **WithAuditColumns**

I was able to add a method CreateTableWithAuditColumns.Where I can use it as,

```
this.CreateTableWithAuditColumns("MyTablename", table => 
                table.WithColumn("Id").AsInt32().NotNullable());
```

Extension method,

```
public static IFluentSyntax CreateTableWithAuditColumns(this MigrationBase self, string tableName, Func<ICreateTableWithColumnOrSchemaOrDescriptionSyntax, IFluentSyntax> constructTableFunction, string schemaName = "dbo")
{
    if (!self.Schema.Schema(schemaName).Table(tableName).Exists())
    {
        var newTable = self.Create.Table(tableName).WithColumn("DateCreated").AsDateTime().Nullable()
                        .WithColumn("DateModified").AsDateTime().Nullable()
                        .WithColumn("CreatedBy").AsInt32().Nullable()
                        .WithColumn("ModifiedBy").AsInt32().Nullable();

        self.Create.ForeignKey() 
            .FromTable("User").ForeignColumn("UserId")
            .ToTable(tableName).PrimaryColumn("CreatedBy");

        self.Create.ForeignKey()
            .FromTable("User").ForeignColumn("UserId")
            .ToTable(tableName).PrimaryColumn("ModifiedBy");

        return newTable;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am trying to find a way to do this like Create.Table("MyTable")**.WithAuditColumns()** which will add columns and foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way, but it does not support creating FKies

```
 public static ICreateTableWithColumnSyntax WithAuditColumns(this ICreateTableWithColumnSyntax table)
            {
                var tt = table.WithColumn("DateCreated").AsDateTime().Nullable()
                    .WithColumn("DateModified").AsDateTime().Nullable()
                    .WithColumn("CreatedBy").AsInt32().Nullable()
                    .WithColumn("ModifiedBy").AsInt32().Nullable();

                //table.Create.ForeignKey()
                //    .FromTable("User").ForeignColumn("UserId")
                //    .ToTable(tableName).PrimaryColumn("CreatedBy");

                //table.Create.ForeignKey()
                //    .FromTable("User").ForeignColumn("UserId")
                //    .ToTable(tableName).PrimaryColumn("ModifiedBy");

                return tt;
            }
```